# Interface contract confuses static checker

Tags: c#, code-contracts

Assume the following simple code:

```
public class Foo // : IFoo
{
    private string _field;

    public string Property
    {
        get { return _field; }
    }

    private void SetField()
    {
        _field = " foo ";
    }

    private string Method()
    {
        SetField();
        return Property.Trim();
    }
}
```

The static checker is able to prove that `Property` will be not null when `Method` uses it.

Now, I introduce an interface along with a contract and the static checker starts complaining: "Possibly calling a method on a null reference 'this.Property'.

**Is this a bug or am I missing something?**

---

The code with the interface looks like this:

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    private string _field;

    public string Property
    {
        get { return _field; }
    }

    private void SetField()
    {
        _field = " foo ";
    }

    private string Method()
    {
        SetField();
        return Property.Trim();
    }
}

[ContractClass(typeof(IFooContract))]
public interface IFoo
{
    string Property { get; }
}

[ContractClassFor(typeof(IFoo))]
public abstract class IFooContract : IFoo
{
    public string Property
    {
        get { throw new System.NotImplementedException(); }
    }
}
```

My settings are like this:

[image]

I get the following output:

```
[...]
C:\{path}\CC2.cs(11,19): message : CodeContracts: Suggested ensures: Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<System.String>() == this._field);
C:\{path}\CC2.cs(16,13): message : CodeContracts: Suggested ensures: Contract.Ensures(this._field != null);
C:\{path}\CC2.cs(21,13): message : CodeContracts: Suggested ensures: Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<System.String>() != null);
C:\{path}\CC2.cs(21,13): message : CodeContracts: Suggested ensures: Contract.Ensures(this._field != null);
C:\{path}\CC2.cs(21,13): message : CodeContracts: Suggested ensures: Contract.Ensures(this.Property.Trim() != null);
C:\{path}\CC2.cs(21,13): message : CodeContracts: Suggested ensures: Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<System.String>() == this.Property.Trim());
[...]
C:\{path}\CC3.cs(33,13): warning : CodeContracts: Possibly calling a method on a null reference 'this.Property'
[...]
```

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate with .NET 4 as target framework.

Comment: I can't reproduce it with VS 2012 and VS 2010 compiled with C# 5 and 4 respectively. I have the same Code Contracts version and configuration. I only receive 8 `Suggested ensures`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @IlyaIvanov: Did you compile the first or the second code snippet? Only the second snippet shows that behavior. Furthermore, please make sure that your settings are the same as mine.

Comment: I've made sure, that all is identical. Moreover, If I comment `//SetField();` then I receive `CodeContracts: Possibly calling a method on a null reference 'this.Property'`

Comment: @IlyaIvanov: Strange. Are you using the same version I am using? I updated my question with my output. Could you please compare?

Comment: Yes, I have managed to reproduce in both 2010 and 2012. My fault of not uncommenting `// : IFoo` in first snippet. Seems to me like a bug. I will try to play with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem only manifests itself for code inside the class - as is the case in my example - the pragmatic solution is simple:

Use the backing field instead of the property:

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    private string _field;

    public string Property
    {
        get { return _field; }
    }

    private void SetField()
    {
        _field = " foo ";
    }

    private string Method()
    {
        SetField();
        return _field.Trim();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite an answer, but some thoughts on the question. This is not that interface contract, which confuse Code Contracts. I've managed to reproduce this with simple example without `ContractClass` for interface. Just change second example to simple

```
//Foo's declaration

public interface IFoo
{
    string Property { get; }
}
```

And you will get the same error. Even adding `Contract.Assume(_field != null);` on Property field doesn't fix it (it will fix it adding this `Assume` to `SetField` method). I didn't manage to suppress null reference exception warning with Invariants either. The only thing that worked is quite an ugly solution, where you have to provide postcondition for interface contract and give Code Contract's a hint with `assume` in Property field. Full code is shown below

```
public class Foo  : IFoo
{
    private string _field;

    public string Property
    {
        get
        {
            Contract.Assume(_field != null);
            return _field;
        }
    }

    private void SetField()
    {
        _field = " foo ";

    }

    private string Method()
    {
        SetField();
        return Property.Trim();
    }
}
```

---

```
[ContractClass(typeof(IFooContract))]
public interface IFoo
{
    string Property { get; }
}

[ContractClassFor(typeof(IFoo))]
public abstract class IFooContract : IFoo
{
    public string Property
    {
        get
        {
            Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<string>() != null);
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:
As `_field` can be null, I suggest to use this method body to give hints to the analyser, so that it won't bother with null reference warning.

```
private string Method()
{
    SetField();
    Contract.Assume(Property != null);
    return Property.Trim();
}
```

p.s. as John Sonmez says at [pluralsight training regarding Code contracts](http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=code-contracts&highlight=john-sonmez_code-contracts-m1-overview%2a1,2,3!john-sonmez_code-contracts-m2-basic!john-sonmez_code-contracts-m3-digging!john-sonmez_code-contracts-m4-advanced#code-contracts-m1-overview) "Static analysis is a complex, mysterious task, which hardly can be worked out without hints to the analyser suing Assume method calls".

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to investigate it. I am aware of the necessity of `Contract.Assume`. But it can't be used in this scenario, because `Property` is allowed to be `null`.

Comment: Could you check this using invariant in Interface contracts? I think you still need to use some redundant statements, so that static code anallyser will be assured, that `Property` can't have null at that specific line of code

Comment: I am not sure which kind of invariants. Could you be so kind and update your code with that?

Comment: Yes, that's the base of my problem: Property *can* be null. So I can't add all those invariants and ensures.

Comment: `Property can be null` sorry, I misread you former statement as if it can't be null (too much work for one day). I think the simplest solution is to add `Contract.Assume`, because there is no place for Invariants here.